# Understanding ってだけで in this sentence

Tags: grammar, particle-って, particle-だけ

Dad suspects that his daughter's good looking teacher might not be as popular as everyone thinks. When asked why, he responds:

> Dad:「とかく美人はなんやかんや言われるからなァ」
>   Because various things are said about beautiful women
>   Mum:「そうね。美人**ってだけで**生意気だなんて言われたりね」
>   That's right. It's said that *only* beautiful women are cheeky.

Dad then seems to get angry and asks mum how she would know such a thing.

I think my translation of mum's sentence must be wrong. I'm not understanding the 美人ってだけで part. At first I assumed this was equivalent to 美人はだけで. But I think if you use は and だけ together then it must be だけは and not はだけ, so I guess the same is true with って?

Irrespective of that I don't see how translating だけ as 'only' makes any sense here. Nor, why dad would get angry at the comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

美人ってだけで means 美人というだけで、美人という理由だけで. So it is translated as " It's said that beautiful women are cheeky simply because they are beautiful."