# お弁当作ってもらうってだけでも幸せなのに - って Meaning

Tags: particle-って

って can be for quotation or like topic marking right?

[image]

お弁当作ってもらうってだけでも幸せなのに

Deepl Translation: I'm happy just to have someone make me lunch.

If this is like a topic marking use of って which I think it is, then why is there no nominalization of もらう?　 Is the casualness of って making it so nominalization is optional?  Or is it a different use?

Comment: Related: [だからって and ってだけで difference](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/47301/43676), [Understanding ってだけで in this sentence](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/39130/43676)

Answer (score 1):

When `ってだけでも` is written down, it becomes `というだけでも`, which implies `ということだけでも`. `だけ` here means "only" and `だけでも` means like "enough only with something".

So, the given sentence represents like, "I'm already luck enough only with the fact that `お弁当作ってもらう`, (but you're still surving me more.)"

It is similar to `というだけで`, which means "only because of the reason". They provide a minimum condition.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your question is about the second って after もらう. This is a topic marking use as you said, but you missed that だけ nominalizes お弁当作ってもらう. I feel like it forms an adverb rather than a noun, though.

Examples:

> 考えるだけでぞっとする

> 食って寝るだけでお金がもらえる仕事はないですか?

> 2、3分外を歩くだけで頭がクラクラしてきた